# Wrapping Featured Image on Add/Edit Page in div?

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails

is it possible to wrap the featured image on the add/edit page in a div or other code? I don't mean on the front page of the website, but on the back end on the add/edit pages when you're typing up your post. I'm trying to add this code around it:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Featured Image Code</p>
</div>
```

The code for the featured image is in `\wp-admin\includes\post.php` but if I add it there it'll be lost when I upgrade.

Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111428/change-width-of-featured-image-thumbnail-on-add-edit-post-page) @PontusAbrahamsson answered you with a good function:

```
function wpse_111428_change_feature_image_admin( $content ) 
{
    global $post;
    $size = 100;

    $id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );

    if( $id )
    {
        return wp_get_attachment_link( $id, array( $size, $size ) );
    }
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse_111428_change_feature_image_admin' );
```

just replace it with a modded version that use code taken from `\wp-admin\includes\post.php`:

```
function wpse_111435_change_feature_image_admin( $content, $post_id = null )  {

  $size = 100; // set here your size

  $thumb = $post_id ? get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true ) : false;

  if( $thumb ) {
    $set_thumbnail_link = '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="' . esc_attr__( 'Set featured image' );
    $set_thumbnail_link .= '" href="%s" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">' . __( 'Set featured image' ) . '</a></p>';
    $upload_iframe_src = esc_url( get_upload_iframe_src('image', $post_id ) );

    $content = '<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><p>' . __('Featured Image Code') . '</p>'; // your html

    $content .= wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb, array( $size, $size ) ) . '</div>'; // this one output the image

    $content .= sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src );
    $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post_id );
    $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">';
    return $content . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</a></p>';
  }

  return $content;

}

add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse_111435_change_feature_image_admin', 20, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no.

The Edit Post screen in WordPress admin only provides the ability for you to upload, edit, and set a featured image for a post or page, but does not provide the ability to change the markup associated with a featured image.

I would suggest adding the code you wish to wrap around your image to your pages template:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

This should be placed inside of the loop of course.

Comment: I think short answer is **yes**. After that, if OP said: > _"I don't mean on the front page of the website, but on the back end"_ why did you say to put code in template files, inside the loop?